# serialise a list by staying in another serialiser

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

This is my output that should look like

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "errors": "",
    "results": [
        {
            "car_type": "sedan",
            "is_active": true,
            "company": {
                ["tata","hyundai"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And my model is,

```
class CarType(CommonBase):
    car_type = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    company = models.ManyToManyField('Company', null=True,
                                      blank=True)


class Company(CommonBase):
    company_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

how i should write my serialiser for a get API to return all car type with `is_active = True`

Comment: You can do the filter in **views.py** in the queryset method

Comment: i have done that. but the problem is i am getting only ids inside ```company``` rather than its name

Comment: its output is like ```{
    "status": 1,
    "errors": "",
    "results": [
        {
            "car_type": "sedan",
            "is_active": true,
            "company": {
                1,2
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That

```
{
     "company": {[...]}
}
```

dictionary thing in the company serialization doesn't make sense, instead what you want there is an actual list.

Focusing just on the item serialization in the `results` you could use a serializer like:

```
class CarTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_company(self, obj):
        return [company.company_name for company in obj.company.all()]

    class Meta:
        model = CarType
        fields = ("car_type", "is_active", "company")
```

which will yield an output like:

```
{
    "car_type": "Car type..",
    "is_active": true,
    "company": [
        "company 1",
        "company 2"
    ]
}
```